# Javascript to open multiple tabs in single browser

Tags: javascript, browser, tabs

Does anyone know how to open multiple URL's in a single browser.
Instead of opening multiple windows, I want the urls to open in tabs in IE.
I am trying to approach this using JavaScript.

Answer (score 6):

This strictly is a user preference in the browser and never try to override that.

Answer (score 0):

For actual browser tabs, the only thing you can do is add the `target="_blank"` attribute to links. This may open tabs, but it may open windows instead. It's a user preference, like phoenix said. (By the way, Firefox, Chrome and Opera all opens "blank" targets in tabs by default.)

The other solution is to use Javascript tabs within the page itself. If you use jQuery, there are some plugins mentioned on [this article I just read](http://www.noupe.com/jquery/35-fresh-useful-jquery-plugins.html). Otherwise, do a bit of Googling for pure JS solutions.

Answer (score 0):

What about if it's Internet Explorer only?

Also, Greg's original question was about JavaScript but would it be possible to make a simple ActiveX/.NET object that could do this and you could call from JavaScript and pass URL as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can say "never try to override that"  but if the user is in a closed environment in which the browser us under control of the administrator, then the user has no choice.  Browsers are used for much more than the web.  A browser on a corporate site does not belong to the user, it belongs to the corporation.